# creating a pandas dataframe from a list of image files

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe from a list of image files (.png files)

```
samples = []
img = misc.imread('a.png')
X = img.reshape(-1, 3)
samples.append(X)
```

I added multiple .png files in samples like this. I am then trying to create a pandas dataframe from this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(samples)
```

It is throwing error "ValueError: Must pass 2-d input". What is wrong here? Is it really possible to convert a list of image files to pandas dataframe. I am totally new to panda, so do not mind if this looks silly.
For ex.
`X = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]                                                                 df = pd.DataFrame(X)`
gives me a nice dataframe of samples 2 as expected (row 2 column 4), but it is not happening with image files.

Comment: `DataFrame()` expects a single array as input, doesn't it, not a list?

Comment: What do you want to do next with the data from the images?

Comment: I need to implement Isomap on that and later need to create a 2d scatter plot from that, But I did not go up to that far. Also please see the last section of my question, I edited it.

Comment: An image is 2-dimensional data. A DataFrame is 2-dimensional. If you want an array of images that would be 3-dimensional data, so you could use a `Panel`, or a Python list of DataFrames, but not a single DataFrame. Alternatively I think you could store the image objects in a 1-dimensional `Series`, but I'm not sure how that would help.

Comment: What do you expect the shape of the `DataFrame` to be?

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(samples)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a DataFrame from a list, the easiest way to do this is to create a `pandas.Series`, like the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

samples = ['a','b','c']
s = pd.Series(samples)
print s
```

output:

---

> 0    a
>   1    b
>   2    c

Comment: please see the last section of my question, I edited it.

Comment: This creates a Series, not a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

```
X = img.reshape(-1, 3)
samples.append(X)
```

So X is a 2D array of size (number_of_pixels,3), and that makes samples a 3D list of size (number_of_images, numbers_pixels, 3) . So the error you're getting ( "ValueError: Must pass 2-d input") is legitimate.

what you probably want is :

```
X = img.flatten()
```

or

```
X = img.reshape(-1)
```

either is going to give you  X of size (number_of_pixels*3,) and samples of size (number_of_images, number_of_pixels*3).

you will probably take extra care to ensure that all images have the same number of pixels and channels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reshape(-1)

```
x.append((img[::2,::2]/255.0).reshape(-1)) 
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```